# Is function Injective? Is function surjective? Let R := {r∈R|r>0} and f :R⟶ R given by f(x) = {x if x∈R and x^2 if x∉R}

Tags: functions, real-numbers

First time on here! I have no idea why this is giving me so much trouble. I'm definitely overthinking it...

Let ℝ⁺:= {r ∈ ℝ⁺|r > 0} and f :ℝ⁺⟶ ℝ⁺ given by f(x) = {x if x ∈ ℝ⁺ and 
                                                 x^2 if x ∉ ℝ⁺}
Is function Injective? 
Is function surjective?

My thoughts:
Injective done by cases:
Case 1:
Let x1, x2 ∈ ℝ⁺ such that f(x1)=f(x2). 
Since f(x1) = x1 & f(x2) = x2 then x1=x2. injective for that case.
Case 2: let x1, x2 ∉ ℝ⁺. 
This is where I'm confused... since x1, x2 are not in ℝ⁺ then they can not be mapped in f: ℝ⁺⟶ ℝ⁺. Am I wrong in thinking this? What would be a more explicit way to prove this? If x1, x2 are not in ℝ⁺ then they are negative which the function squares and thus would be positive and apart of the codomain. But, there is no negative x in ℝ⁺ to map that to... Please any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean $f: R \rightarrow R^+$?

Comment: You are definitely overthinking it when you can simply draw its graph.

Comment: Excuse me, but if $f:\Bbb R^+\to\Bbb R^+$ as you wrote, considering the case $x\notin \Bbb R^+$ is pointless, since that case simply **never** occurs.

Comment: Your definition of R (or R+) has an infinite loop!

Comment: The function is explicitly written as R+→R+. Must be an error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: *Something* has to be incorrect with how you have written out the problem. What is the use of defining $\mathbb{R^+}=\{r\in\mathbb{R^+}\mid r>0\}$? You define something in terms of itself? And as Sassatelli points out, the condition for the definition of the function makes no sense when the domain does not include nonpositive reals.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, then notice that $f(1)=f(-1)=1$ but $1 \neq -1$. Thus, the function is not injective. It is surjective since for any $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $f(a)=a$.

If you meant $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, then $f$ is the identity function on $ \mathbb{R}^+$, and thus it is a bijection.

Also, as @Bernard pointed out, your definition of $ \mathbb{R}^+$ is incorrect. It should be $\mathbb{R}^+:= \{r \in \mathbb{R} | r>0\}$

Answer (score 0):

if $f:\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ as defined above, then $f(x)$ is a bijection.

Every for every $y$ in the co-domain there is one, and only one, $x$ in the domain such that $f(x) = y.$